# Youtube Webscraping Comments by new

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pyautogui

I'm trying to web scrape a youtube comment section. But before that, I want to sort the comments by new. So I have to click on the SORT BY and then Newest First. But unfortunately, I have no luck. Thank you for helping out.

Screen record: https://i.stack.imgur.com/efZVl.jpg

code:

```
import sys, unittest, time, datetime
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import InvalidArgumentException
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import requests.exceptions
from urllib.parse import urlsplit
from collections import deque
import re
import os
import shutil
import smtplib
import string
import pyautogui

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--lang=en')
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\caspe\OneDrive\Documents\Övrigt\Kodning\Email\chromeDriver\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EV6PLN_8RBw")
time.sleep(5)

screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size()
currentMouseX, currentMouseY = pyautogui.position()

pyautogui.moveTo(1050, 780) # Move the mouse to XY coordinates.
pyautogui.click()
print("clicked")
time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.moveTo(1250, 880) # Move the mouse to XY coordinates.
pyautogui.click() 
print("clicked")
time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.moveTo(700, 500) # Move the mouse to XY coordinates.
pyautogui.click() 
print("clicked")
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: _...have to click on the SORT BY and then Newest First..._, no luck at which line?

Comment: Unfortunately both

Comment: I tried to use both XPath and full XPath but it doesn't find the elements on the site. (the last two rows)

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend to replace the autogui part with firstly
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath or by css_selector and element.click
And after you choose the xpath/css_selector from the "Newest" option and click again, i did that in another script and had no problems, i cant format it right since im on android tho

tl;dr: replace the autogui by clicking with selenium, firstly the button that makes the options chooseable and then again on the option you want to sort it for

Edit: okay i tried it out myself, the pyautogui did not work for me, not sure if it is because of me using another driver or something, but if it works for you thats fine. The problem is, that you need to scroll down a bit first, in order to load the comments. you can do that using

```
for i in range(5):
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 500)", element)
time.sleep(2)
```

not sure if 5 is enough/too much, since i cant check myself, but thats basically how it would work. you can then locate the dropdown open button using

```
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="label"]")
    element.click
    #now we select the option from the dropdown options
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[4]/div[1]/div/ytd-comments/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[1]/ytd-comments-header-renderer/div[1]/span/yt-sort-filter-sub-menu-renderer/yt-dropdown-menu/paper-menu-button/iron-dropdown/div/div/paper-listbox/a[2]/paper-item")  
    element.click
```

you could also use explicitWaits to ensure it is in view, but i dont feel confortable using that yet, you find them [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)
try it out and let me know if it worked :D

Comment: the reason I use autogui is because the pop up with accept terms on google pages didn't allow me to click with xpath. If you have time later, could you send me the code on how you are able to click on the sort and newest? I tried using both xpath, full xpath put unfortunately it doesn't find the path.

Comment: For the pop-up you will probably need autogui, i seen that problem in another question, yet not solved. I will have to try myself if that works first, but im on it ^^

Comment: for a 1920x1080 screen, the code to remove the pop up is in the code section!

Comment: currently writing an answer, possibly i have to maximize the window not sure

Comment: unfortunately no luck. I get no errors but the element doesn't get clicked. There is a screen record in the post

Comment: sorry to hear that, what you can try is to either take the css_selector or to take another button, since there are like 3 different ones defined, i wasnt sure which one to take, id suggest to try and error a bit

Comment: unfortunately, after many tries non of them worked... Thank you any ways kind starnger!

Comment: I guess im out of ideas then

Comment: Thank you anyway! I'm going to try to build a couple of different auto clickers with pyautogui. But unfortunately, the button moves too much depending on the video...