# Python Pyautogui Clicking via Coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pyautogui

I'm trying to get the position of an element. I return the coordinates but unfortunately, it always clicks in the wrong position. The x coordinate is right but the y is always wrong. With a bit testing, I think it's because I scrolled down on the page. Due to the clickable element is out of view I have to scroll down. Is there a way to fix this? I did a temporary solution by just x the element with a variable. But this solution feels like it only will apply in certain situations.

Note that in this situation I'm not able to use the find_xpath due to the button not being clickable this way. See post [Youtube Webscraping Comments by new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080915/youtube-webscraping-comments-by-new)

```
newX = 0
newY = 0

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--lang=en')
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\caspe\OneDrive\Documents\Övrigt\Kodning\Email\chromeDriver\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvbtXv8dy00")
time.sleep(3)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,15)
for item in range(10): 
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body"))).send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
time.sleep(2)

browser_location = driver.get_window_position()
print(browser_location)

e = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ytd-app/ytd-popup-container/paper-dialog/yt-upsell-dialog-renderer/div/div[3]/div[1]/yt-button-renderer/a/paper-button/yt-formatted-string")
position = str(e.location)
x = 1.03*(int((position.split("x': ")[1].split(", 'y':")[0])))
y = 0.73*(int((position.split("'y': ")[1].split("}")[0])))
pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
pyautogui.click() 
print("clicked")
time.sleep(2)

pyautogui.moveTo(1200, 830)
pyautogui.click() 
print("clicked")
time.sleep(2)

for item in range(5): 
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body"))).send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
time.sleep(2)

browser_location = driver.get_window_position()
print(browser_location)

e = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[4]/div[1]/div/ytd-comments/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[1]/ytd-comments-header-renderer/div[1]/span")
print(e.location)
position = str(e.location)

print(position.split("x': ")[1].split(", 'y':")[0])
print(position.split("'y': ")[1].split("}")[0])

x = int((position.split("x': ")[1].split(", 'y':")[0]))
y = int((position.split("'y': ")[1].split("}")[0]))

if y == 1215:
    newY = 0.77*y
if x == 250:
    newX = 1.12*x
if y == 1091:
    newY = 0.74*y

pyautogui.moveTo(newX, newY)
pyautogui.click() 
print("clicked")
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: the basic problem is that e.location won't change when you scroll... it's relative to the DOM/browser viewport.  Your pyautogui coordinates are for the screen.

Comment: Alright, but the weird thing is that then it shouldn't be a problem. But each time I run the code to find the position of the element it always returns the y coordinate as 1090. The object is clearly not in that range. Could it be returning the wrong coordinates?

Comment: no that is a problem because e.location is relative to the browser's viewport.  That location will not change when scrolled... however the position relative to the screen will change.  In fact, 0,0 is different in each context.

Comment: alright, gotcha. With a bit of testing and using `pyautogui.scroll(-750)`. Then naturally I should just remove 750 from the y coordinate. But removing 500 clicks right on the object. Does this just show that the coordinates are inaccurate? `y = y-500`

Comment: there's going to be an initial offset.. (the height of the browser's controls at the top... ) and then the amount of pixels scrolled.   You may also have to account for dpi/resolution.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Thank you!